# Effect on performance of large setTimeout time

Tags: javascript

I need to display a notice every hour, or at certain hourly intervals.  I was wondering what the effect on performance is of having such a large time out time?

`setTimeout(function(){ ... } ,60*60*1000)`

The timer doesn't have to be perfect and can be a couple of milliseconds out.

Comment: What do you mean by performance? CPU-call needed by that code?

Comment: Does it have to be JS? If not, I suggest using `crontab`

Comment: If this reoccurs would you not need `setInterval` instead?

Comment: If you want it to run at certain intervals you might want to use setInterval ([W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)). But by resources do you mean if this will slow down the site in general if this JS is running?

Comment: Similar question maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670273/javascript-timed-notifications-settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeOut()` (or `setInterval()` for that matter) itself is not expensive (performance-wise) at all: after all, it's just a check to see if the determined time has passed.

The "time" you determine doesn't change the performance at all. A `setTimeOut(function() {;},  100);` is as expensive as `setTimeOut(function() {;}, 1000);`.

What **might** slow down your site/app is the code that has to run when the timeout triggers.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is no... you don't have performace problems... but i think you needs to use SetInterval instead SetTimeout to repeat the call every x time